# Jest toHaveBeenCalledWith one in array of possible values

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

Is there a way to create a jest-test to test for something like this:

```js
test("called with one of a, b, or c", () => {
  let someMock = jest.fn()
  someMock("c")
  // Desired behavior:
  expect(someMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.oneOf(["a", "b", "c"]))
})
```

Essentially, I have an enum of possible values that I expect the mock to be called with. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: You can see the built-in matchers on https://jestjs.io/docs/expect. Maybe get the value it was called with and assert that an array of allowed values contains it?

Comment: I ended up just mocking out the parts which had variable return type, but this features seems like something that could be desirable for more people to have in the library.

Comment: Any requests for new matchers will generally be pushed to `jest-extended`, which already has an asymmetrical `toBeOneOf` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharp mentioned in a comment, there is a [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) module which has the [.toBeOneOf](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/tobeoneof) operator which does exactly what I was looking for.